# bootstrap collapsed mobile navbar not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar which when it opens on a mobile screen, it doesn't break into the little menu button as it should.

If I test it on Chrome, and reduce the size of the screen, the navbar collapses into the mobile, but opening on a mobile screen, wont work.

My question is: is it my navbar problem? Where can I check where the navbar collapses?

this is my navbar

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu">
        <li id="posts">
          <%= link_to "POSTS", posts_path %>
        </li>
        <li id="athletes">
          <%= link_to "ATLETAS", athletes_path %>
        </li>
        <li id="videos">
          <%= link_to "VIDEOS", videos_path %>
        </li>
        <li id="products">
          <%= link_to "PRODUTOS", products_path %>
        </li>
        <li id="cardapio">
          <%= link_to "CARDAPIO", menus_path %>
        </li>
        <li id="recipes">
          <%= link_to "RECEITAS", recipes_path %>
        </li>
        <li id="contact">
          <%= link_to "QUEM SOMOS", new_contact_path%>
        </li>
        <% if session[:adm] == "true" %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "SAIR", :controller => "adms", :action => "singOut"%>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: have you included the required JavaScript file in your html?

Comment: You should take the time to post your complete, rendered HTML, not just your Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you don't have the needed JS to make things work.

> Requires JavaScript plugin
>
> If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the
>   navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view
>   the content within the .navbar-collapse.
>
> The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin to be included in
>   your version of Bootstrap.

try adding

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

OR

```
<!-- Twitter Bootstrap Core JS -->
<script src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

to your html file below the CSS includes.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem to this in the past, and I found I had missed the line.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added this line in your header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```